# How to achieve a fade in transition when changing the inner html of a page

Tags: javascript, forms, css-transitions, innerhtml, display

I'm trying to achieve an effect when a form is used on my website. Basically when the user presses submit the innerhtml changes to a thank you message but I want it to look smoother, perhaps with a fade in opacity. I tried a CSS transition to no avail. Any ideas how to do this? Thanks and apologies for errors, I'm a bit of a noob.

```
        </div>
        <form id="ContactForm" form action="" method='get'>
            <input type="text" id="ContactFirstName" placeholder="First Name" required>
            <input type="text" id="ContactLastName" placeholder="Last Name" required>
            <br>
            <input type="email" id="ContactEmail" placeholder="Your Email" required>
            <select id="ContactPackage" required></script>
                <option value="">- Choose Your Package -</option>
                <option value="Standard">Standard($20)</option>
              <option value="Custom">Custom($40)</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <input type="file" name="img" id="ContactFile" class="inputfile" required/>
            <br>
            <textarea id="ContactNotes" rows="4" cols="30" placeholder="Any specific notes here!"></textarea>
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="OrderTotal" size="5" placeholder="$0" disabled>
            <input type="submit" id="ContactSubmit" value="Purchase">
        </form>
        <div id="DisplayResults"></div>
    </div>


    #ContactForm{
    flex-direction: column;
    line-height: 2;
    background-color:  rgba(129, 164, 205, 1);
    border: 1px solid  rgba(129, 164, 205, 1);
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 30px;
    }

    #ContactForm input, select, textarea{
    font-size: 1em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }

    #OrderTotal{
    width: 5em;
    background-color: rgba(129, 164, 205, 1);
    color: rgba(219, 228, 238, 1);
    }

    #DisplayResults{
    color: rgba(219, 228, 238, 1);
    }


    document.getElementById("ContactForm").addEventListener("submit", 
    sendformtosite);

    var SubmitButton = document.getElementById('ContactSubmit');


    function sendformtosite(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

   var FormFirstName = 
   document.getElementById('ContactFirstName').value,
   FormLastName = document.getElementById('ContactLastName').value,
   FormEmail = document.getElementById('ContactEmail').value,
   FormPackage = document.getElementById('ContactPackage').value,
   FormFile = document.getElementById('ContactFile').value,
   FormNotes = document.getElementById('ContactNotes').value

   console.log(FormFirstName, FormLastName, FormEmail, FormPackage, 
   FormFile, FormNotes);
   // alert("Thank you for your order!");


   //end of function//


   //display totals//
    document.getElementById("BookingIntro").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ContactForm").style.display = "none";

    var DisplayTheResults = document.getElementById('DisplayResults');

    DisplayTheResults.innerHTML = 'Thank you for your order ' + FormFirstName + "!"+ '<br>';
    DisplayTheResults.innerHTML += 'You ordered the Clean My Headshot ' + FormPackage + ' package.' + '<br>';
    DisplayTheResults.innerHTML += 'Your finished photo will be sent to ' + FormEmail + '<br>';

    }
```

Comment: Instead of `display = none` you will want to use `opacity = 0` and add `transition: opacity 0.5s` to the appropriate classes substituting your desired transition length where I place`0.5s`

Comment: Worked great! Thanks!